# Kubernetes ingress How to set default-ssl-certificate?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I have a generic SSL certificate *.domain.com
I want configure a HTTPS for a 4 level domain (my4.level.domain.com)
I read [in this discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2667), that i need to use  [--default-ssl-certificate](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/cli-arguments/)

But i don't understand how to use it

How should I change this configuration?

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations: {}
  labels: {}
  path: /
  hosts:
    - my4.level.domain.com
  extraPaths: []
  tls:
   - secretName: tls-tierra-ingress
     hosts:
       - '*.level.domain.com'
       - level.domain.com
       - my4.level.domain.com
```

Or do I have to run a special command?

Comment: For anyone using the `ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx` Helm chart, I answered this same question but explaining how to do it on the values.yaml on this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71877715/2905274

Answer (score 11):

For people who are looking into this issue in the future:

## TLDR

If you are installing ingress-nginx with helm, you will need to specify `default-ssl-certificate` by using [controller.extraArgs found within values.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/e079486d4dc40387389adbaed7ec9b80d897d810/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L180)

```
  --set controller.extraArgs.default-ssl-certificate="__NAMESPACE__/_SECRET__" \
```

## Non-TLDR

My setup

- cert-manager + [origin-ca-issuer](https://github.com/cloudflare/origin-ca-issuer#installing-origin-ca-issuer) (I'm using `origin-ca-issuer` namespace)

  1. [create cloudflare key as secret + origin issuer](https://github.com/cloudflare/origin-ca-issuer#adding-an-originissuer)
  2. [create certificate](https://github.com/cloudflare/origin-ca-issuer#creating-our-first-certificate)
- dns zone in cloudflare + dns entry pointing to load balancer + TLS full + strict
- create ingress-nginx with helm

```
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
  --version 4.2.5 \
  --create-namespace \
  --namespace ingress-nginx \
  --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.registry=k8s.gcr.io \
  --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.image=ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen \
  --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.tag=v1.1.1 \
  --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.digest="" \
  --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
  --set controller.extraArgs.default-ssl-certificate="origin-ca-issuer/wildcard-domain-name-secret" \
  --set controller.image.registry=k8s.gcr.io \
  --set controller.image.image=ingress-nginx/controller \
  --set controller.image.tag=v1.3.1 \
  --set controller.image.digest="" \
  --set controller.kind=DaemonSet \
  --set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
  --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-path"=/ \
  --set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local
```

The benefit of this setup is that it allows me to avoid writing `tls` block in every ingress manifest.

Comment: Thanks a million. I worked to enable TLS for many days for Azure Kubernetes Service with unmanaged ingress controller. I was about to run crazy. Command `--set controller.extraArgs.default-ssl-certificate="__NAMESPACE__/_SECRET__"` saved my life :).
For possible future searchings (To create tls secret):
`kubectl create secret tls <secret-name> --key <tls-key-full-path> --cert <cert-key-full-path>`

Comment: `--set controller.extraArgs.default-ssl-certificate="origin-ca-issuer/wildcard-domain-name-secret" \`
This line solved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

`--default-ssl-certificate` is an argument used inside `Ingress controller`. [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/cli-arguments.md) is a list of all command line arguments that are accepted by the Ingress Controller.

To see which arguments are used you can do `kubectl describe deployment/nginx-ingress-controller --namespace`

You might see:

```
Args:
  --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
  --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
  --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
```

You can edit the controller `yaml` and put what's needed by your setup, if You don't have the file you can save deployed ingress as `ingress-controller.yaml` by using:
`kubectl get deployment/nginx-ingress-controller --namespace -o yaml > ingress-controller.yaml`

Also you can edit the `ingress` on the fly by using:
`kubectl edit deployment/nginx-ingress-controller --namespace`

As for 4 level domain SSL Certificate, I haven't tried that so sadly I cannot help.

Comment: In case someone installs Nginx Ingress Controller via Helm, you need to `kubectl edit deployment nginx-ingress-controller -n <namespace>` and add the `--default-ssl-certificate` arg into `args:`. Then restart nginx ingress controller.

Comment: @dvdblk In [kubernetes/nginx-ingress Helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/charts/ingress-nginx) it is possible to pass the controller argument using `controller.extraArgs` value.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Helm to deploy my ingress but was not able to set `controller.extraArgs`, so I patched the nginx controller using:

```
kubectl patch deployment "nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller" \
    -n "default" \
    --type "json" \
    --patch '[{"op":"add","path":"/spec/template/spec/containers/0/args/-","value":"--default-ssl-certificate=default/certificate"}]'
```

Comment: As I checked here https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/README.md, it should be something like this:

$ helm install stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.extraArgs.v=2
for example:
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.extraArgs.default-ssl-certificate=default/certificate

Answer (score 1):

i dont have kubernetes, but judging by this article:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/

you need to specify the default secret with the parameter --default-ssl-ceritifcate in the ingress controller, and then just remove the "secretName" option in the yalm, and it should use the default certificate.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure you have a wildcard certificate, go ahead and see how its done with certbot:

https://certbot.eff.org/glossary#wildcard-certificate

for sub-subdomains you have to specify the subdomain when creating the certificate, e.g.:

```
user$: certbot certonly --manual \
        --preferred-challenges=dns \
        --email your-email@gmil.com \
        --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory \
        --agree-tos \
        -d '*.level.domain.com' -d '*.domain.com' -d domain.com
```

then you'll have to do a dns challenge to verify it's your domain.
with certbot "* . * .example.com" is not valid, i dont know if its possible with any other certificate authority, but if you want this to be dynamic, you better use kubernetes cert manager to issue certificates on the spot when an ingress rule is created.

you can add --default-ssl-certificate with this command:

> kubectl edit deployment ingress-nginx-controller

then you add it under  spec.template.spec.containers.args

if you want to have one cert. for all, then after passing the dns challenge and getting the .pem files, first you create a tls secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: tls-secret
data:
  # fullchain.pem converted to base64 (all 3 certificates dont remove line breaks before converting)
  tls.crt: "LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQLS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQ.......BTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkF=="
  # privekey.pem converted to base64 (dont remove line breaks before converting)
  tls.key: "LS0tLS1CRUd.......XcwQkFRRUZBQVN=="
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

then create an ingress rule with tls:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    #ingress-nginx-controller has to be installed/created
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: sub.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: http-svc
                port:
                  number: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - sub.domain.com
    secretName: tls-secret
```

Comment: I dislike this option since it violates DRY pretty badly. Needing to specify `tls.secretName` in _each_ `Ingress` resource definition is not ideal.

Comment: @BradSolomon you are right, thats why i said you can use cert manager, but its also possible to use Reflector to solve this issue:
https://github.com/emberstack/kubernetes-reflector
reflector basically reflects your Secret or ConfigMap in all or chosen namespaces, you can also set it to reflect automatically or on demand. meaning you can set the tls-secret in one namespace and ingress rule will always find it's "mirrored" clone, to change it everywhere you just change the source tls-secret that reflects.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, nginx ingress controller is installed as part of rke2 installation.
rke2-ingress-nginx-controller is installed as DaemonSet, so patch needs to be done on DaemonSet.

```
scripts # kubectl get DaemonSet -A
NAMESPACE       NAME                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
calico-system   calico-node                     1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   23d
kube-system     rke2-ingress-nginx-controller   1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   23d
scripts #
```

Make sure the certificate state is **Ready**

```
scripts # kubectl get certificate -A
NAMESPACE   NAME                             READY   SECRET                  AGE
mynamespace default-ingress-tls-certificate  True  default-ingress-tls    108m
scripts #
```

patch command shall be,

RESOURCE-NAME - based on the **kubectl get DaemonSet -A**, can be etiher Deployment/DaemonSet

RNAMESPACE - based on the **kubectl get DaemonSet -A**

CNAMESPACE, SECRET-NAME - based on the command **kubectl get certificate -A**

> kubectl patch  "rke2-ingress-nginx-controller" 
> -n "[RNAMESPACE]" 
> --type "json" 
> --patch '[{"op":"add","path":"/spec/template/spec/containers/0/args/-","value":"--default-ssl-certificate=[CNAMESPACE]/[SECRET-NAME]"}]'

example:

> kubectl patch DaemonSet "rke2-ingress-nginx-controller" 
> -n "kube-system" 
> --type "json" 
> --patch '[{"op":"add","path":"/spec/template/spec/containers/0/args/-","value":"--default-ssl-certificate=mynamespace/default-ingress-tls"}]'

Thanks to @mirkw00d